# Why I could not Ansible ping my testerver?

Tags: ansible, ping

I am trying to run example from Ansible Up and Running book.

My playbooks directory

```
ls
ansible.cfg  hosts  ubuntu-bionic-18.04-cloudimg-console.log  Vagrantfile
```

hosts

```
testserver ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_port=2222
```

ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
inventory = hosts
remote_user = vagrant
private_key_file = .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
host_key_checking = False
```

Vagrantfile

```
   config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
```

When I try ping

```
ansible testserver -m ping
```

I got

```
testserver | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
    "rc": 127
}
```

I can ssh without any problems

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 -i /home/miki/playbooks/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-50-generic x86_64)


  System information as of Tue May 21 06:39:46 UTC 2019

  System load:  0.0               Processes:             108
  Usage of /:   18.5% of 9.63GB   Users logged in:       0
  Memory usage: 17%               IP address for enp0s3: 10.0.2.15
  Swap usage:   0%





Last login: Tue May 21 06:32:13 2019 from 10.0.2.2
```

Why ansible ping does not work?

Comment: try to add this in hosts file 
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error as well. Then found this:

```
"module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found\r\n",
```

As python is installed in local host, and python is not installed in the remote host, just installed python in the remote host. And found the problem is solved !!!

Answer (score 4):

From the error message

```
"module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found\r\n",
```

it seems the remote host does not have python installed.

Quoting from the [requiremet docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#managed-node-requirements)

> *On the managed nodes, you need a way to communicate, which is normally ssh. By default this uses sftp. If that’s not available, you can switch to scp in ansible.cfg. You also need Python 2 (version 2.6 or later) or Python 3 (version 3.5 or later).*

Ansible needs python to be present  in remote host.

Also, about the usage of `ping` module, [it's not the same as `ping` shell command.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ping_module.html)

Try installing python in the remote host (either manually or using `raw` module) and then re-run the script.

Answer (score 2):

This is just because you are mixing up ansible [`ping`](/clavel.loc/everest/home/olcla/Drive/Dropbox/ComptaThoteam/000-inbox/FraisFacturesJustificatifs/2019-04) module and classic ICMP ping command in your terminal which are not equivalent. From the above link

> This is NOT ICMP ping, this is just a trivial test module that requires Python on the remote-node.

With the above confusion, you are miss-interpreting the clear error messages you are getting when running the playbook:

First

> Shared connection to 127.0.0.1 closed

... which means a connection was first opened and that your host is reachable

Second

> /bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found

... which means that python (required for ansible) is not installed or not in a default path.